# Looking for a knowledge-based Q&A app for an asp.net website, but more than a FAQ

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have an engineering website made in Visual Studio / VB / .NET 4.0.  I'm looking for an application that can act as a knowledge base for questions and answers engineers might have regarding machine vision.

The best idea I can come up with right now is to make a simple FAQ, and then have a form-mail on a separate page that gets sent to me when an engineer has a question.  This way, I could pass on the question to an engineer, and he/she could answer it, and I'd put it up on the FAQ.

*Example:  Q: Is there a multiple-camera system for bead detection?
           A:  Yes, you can look at the USS Bead Tracker in conjunction with PPT software*

I'm not great with databases, know nothing of MVC, but here's the one solution that seemed best:  [FAQ Knowledge Base](http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/faq-generator-27687/) and then I could have a page set up with form mail that gets sent to me when someone has a question they want added to the knowledge base.

Am I going about this the right way?  Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAQ are typically set up with the an admin asking a question then providing an answer.

I think a forum might be better suited for you.  Where a user ask a question and a moderator can answering them.  There a plenty of free forums available that can be set up to send emails as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave; appreciate the advice!